# How to calculate sum of log terms with different base?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

I evaluated an algorithm having run-time complexity which follows the following log series:

(log<sub>2</sub> n + 1) + (log<sub>3</sub> n + 2) + (log<sub>4</sub> n + 3) +.....+ (log<sub>n</sub> n + (n - 1))

How can I figure out the time complexity of this algorithm in terms of 'big O' notation?

Comment: conversion between different log bases is constant, so you can usually assume all are log 2

Comment: @juvian Well here, the base of the logarithm depends on `n`.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the sum of the log terms and the non-log terms separately.

Among the log terms, log<sub>2</sub> n is the largest and there are n-1 terms. The sum is therefore less than (n-1)log<sub>2</sub> n, this is in O(n log n).

The sum of the non-log terms is (n-1)n/2, this is in O(n²).

We see that the sum of the non-log terms dominates the sum of the log terms. Therefore, the result is O(n²).

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this question. I think this is the best answer I have ever come across on the internet for this question.

Comment: Suppose these non-log terms are responsible for doing similar operation(Deletion) for (n-1) times, but log terms are responsible for letting the algorithm to perform important operations that it meant to do. So, can I exclude the sum of non-log terms, i.e. O(n square) from time complexity to make it O(n log n)?

Comment: I don't know which algorithm you are talking about. All you posted was the formula.

Comment: this is a general example in which I allude you what log and non-log terms are responsible for performing in that algorithm? Please take this information succinct and answer me in general way. Thank you.

Comment: There is no way to give a sensible answer. If you are considering a different estimate you get another formula for the effort and another order of growth.

Comment: Thank you so much.